# Ruby on Rails - Carrierwave Error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, rubygems

When attempting to deploy a Ruby on Rails app on Heroku, I keep getting this error (note: it doesn't exist in my AWS Cloud9 Dev. environment). I've been Googling the error all day but can't find anything (the gem file is shown at the bottom of this post)

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   LoadError: cannot load such file -- fog
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:122:in `eager_load_fog'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:137:in `fog_credentials='
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:159:in `configure'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   /tmp/build_5e7923a7e29e56747598006c2e9e9163/AndrewSanford-oafd-9b30ac69df2758e10ba9a44697e3a457f344f4eb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

!
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed

Gemfile (partial):

```html
gem 'rails',                   '5.1.2'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.11'
gem 'faker',                   '1.7.3'
gem 'carrierwave',             '1.1.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.7.0'
gem 'fog-aws',                 '2.0.0'
gem 'nokogiri',                '1.8.1'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.6'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.7'
gem 'puma',                    '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',                '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',              '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.7.0'
```

Production.rb

```html
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
  # Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or
  # `config/secrets.yml.key`.
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "oafd_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'fathomless-island-79606.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have made following changes in your production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

If not make this change and try to deply once again.

Comment: Hmm I didn't have that in the file but added it, and I still got the same error message :/ This is the only "static" code my app has in production.rb:

# Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

Comment: Can you please share the code of your production.rb?

Comment: Yep! Just updated the original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please try after replacing `ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?` with `true`?

Answer (score 0):

can you post your config/initializers/carrierwave.rb ?  it looks like you may be requiring 'fog' but only including 'fog-aws' in the application.  I would think that might also break in development so its weird you're only seeing it when deploying to heroku but it might be related to this: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1648